# ESP32 IC Circuit Schematic

Tags: microcontroller, schematics, esp32

This is my second attempt to design a board with microcontroller chips. From my last question, I learnt a lot and this design has improved from my last one, I believe.
[image]

Once again, what can be some possible improvements in this schematic design?

**UPDATE 1:**
[image]
I tried to solve the issues that you figured out, let me know if my changes are correct and what other things need to be resolved

Comment: Looks good to me at first glance.  I see your antenna design is grounded at the far end, your PCB package is unlikely to know how to deal with that but I’m sure you’re on to it.

Comment: Once again? Are you asking for improvements, or just for the obvious errors it still has?

Comment: @Frog I did that following their official reference schematics actually

Comment: I don’t doubt it, but if you do a polygon pour it will likely cover the entire antenna rather than just connecting at the end.

Answer (score 3):

I'll compile a list here.

- No bypass/bulk caps at all on regulator input
- CH340 power supply connections are not correct for 3.3V VCC operation
- Pushbutton pull-up is useless, as DTR# is output
- Pushbutton will short DTR# output to ground if pushed
- LEDs likely prevent UART receive from working at proper voltage levels

Comment: Yeah I think the DTR# thing is supposed to be for the BOOT switch, but the logic isn't correct here. The CH340's RTS/DTR pins are supposed to drive EN/IO0 on the ESP32, so that programming over USB can automatically initialise code upload and issue a reset once done. The RESET/BOOT pushbuttons should act as manual overrides. This is handled in other designs using a pair of NPNs; I'd advise OP to check out the published schematics for existing ESP32 boards to see how they do it.

Comment: The Ch340 missing capacitors is a great mistake. I did it right last time. Thanks for pointing me. Where should I connect DTR? Directly to the EN pin? The 10k resistor and 1u cap is supposed to be a rc delay circuit as suggested by the datasheet.

Comment: I am looking at the esp8266 board schematic and some articles, I will update my design soon and please see if that is correct.

Comment: I updated my question, please take a look

Comment: @Abrar the CH340 power supplying scheme is still wrong for single-supply 3.3V operation. I don't see any difference. Open the datasheet and look a the diagrams. And now there are new problems.

Comment: Pleas note that this LDO is quite picky as it comes to capacitors. You should use electrolytic ones, NOT ceramic ones. The problem is that 1117 requires relatively high-ESR capacitors. Around 1uF if I remember correctly

Comment: @Justme check the second image. The power is no longer 3.3v, it's from usb regulated 5v

Comment: @Felix that is a good point - datasheet does not say anything about output cap except that a 22uF tantalum will make it stable in all conditions. However ceramic caps can be used if they are slightly farther apart from regulator output, or have an added series resistance. Abrar right so it is powered OK now.

Comment: @Justme you said there are some new problems. Can you please tell me which problems are there?

Comment: I already added the LEDs to the list.

Comment: @Justme Got it. If so, how should I add the LED to indicate data transmission like arduino

Comment: If you really want it to work like an Arduino, then copy the Arduino schematics.

Comment: @Justme nope, but I want a led signal for data transmission, if possible

Answer (score 1):

> *what can be some possible improvements in this schematic design*

I would put test points on all nodes; they don't need to be big test-points but, if you screw up somewhere and want to change things it's easier to make a bodge wire fit a hole and solder it rather that try and solder it to an SMD pad.

This also applies to all the pins on your MCU that *might* be usable.

Every PCB I make I adopt this philosophy. You might as well shower the design with some bulkier test points on ground and Vcc - have about ten or twenty littering the design and spread them around evenly when you design your PCB. You just never know when you want to add an LED or a connector or something you haven't thought of - all these test points (big and small) give you future proofing and flexibility.

I'm not sure what this is all about: -

[image]

Should ground be on both sides of those capacitors? If it's an antenna with a side-by-side ground connection then that's OK but I don't think a 10 μF capacitor is going to help your antenna signal very much. Maybe you meant 10 pF?

I'd also put decoupler capacitors close to all your Vcc pins on the ESP32.

I wouldn't short out a 100 nF capacitor with a switch either; I'd put 10 or 22 ohms in series with the switch to avoid the switch being damaged and avoid glitches.

I would probably also put a hefty 5 watt zener diode across the power rails to cope with silliness when you wire the supply backwards. Also, your regulator (U2) needs capacitors on its input and output. I think it also might be prudent to have a 1 nF 1 kV capacitor from the USB outer-shell pins to local ground; it doesn't need to be fitted but, could be useful if there is a lot of noise and can be bridged-out with a link to give you the connectivity you currently have.

Do you need to have a power connector somewhere - maybe you don't but, it's worth having on on there in case you need to power anything externally.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions! I followed the official reference schematics given in their datasheet for that part. The other part of antenna should be NC as I read from the datasheet of antenna, but esp32 datasheet connected it to ground.

Comment: I have put decoupling capacitors and connected all vcc pins together with them. Should I separate them?

Comment: Ground isn’t on both side of the capacitors, is it? The top side has an antenna in between

Comment: @Ananas_hoi all I have is a picture of a circuit and, if it looks joined up on that picture I can't assume it isn't.

Comment: @Abrar you should have decoupling capacitors located close to each Vcc pin with the other capacitor terminal connecting to a ground plane with a via.

Comment: @Andyaka alright!